# Excel cell lookup in subtotaled range

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup, subtotal

I'd like to use index/match to lookup values in a subtotaled range.  Using the sample data below, from another sheet (Sheet 2), I need to lookup the total NY Company hours for each employee.

Sheet 2:

| Bob      | NY Company         | ????  |

This formula returns the first match of NY Company Total

```
=INDEX('Sheet1!A1:C45,MATCH(Sheet2!B2 & " Total",'Sheet1!B1:B45,0),3)
```

Now I need to expand the lookup to include the Employee (Bob).  Also, Column A is blank on the total Row.  I've started to work with something like the following but no luck.

```
=INDEX('Sheet1!A1:C45,MATCH(1,('Sheet2!B2 & " Total"='Sheet1!B1:B45)*('Sheet2!B1='Sheet1!A1:A45)),3)
```

Also, as the sample data below looks perfect in the preview and then looks really bad after saving, I've added a pic with the sample data.

Sample data:

[image: sample data pic]

Sample Data:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Employee | Customer | Hours |
| Bob | ABC Company | 5 |
| Bob | ABC Company | 3 |
|  | ABC Company Total | 8 |
| Bob | NY Company | 7 |
| Bob | NY Company | 7 |
| Bob | NY Company | 5 |
| Bob | NY Company | 3 |
|  | NY Company Total | 22 |
| Bob | Jet Company | 1 |
|  | Jet Company Total | 1 |
| Carrie | ABC Company | 1 |
| Carrie | ABC Company | 4 |
|  | ABC Company Total | 5 |
| Carrie | NY Company | 6 |
| Carrie | NY Company | 2 |
| Carrie | NY Company | 3 |
|  | NY Company Total | 11 |
| Carrie | Jet Company | 7 |
| Carrie | Jet Company | 9 |
|  | Jet Company Total | 16 |
| Carrie | XYZ Company | 4 |
|  | XYZ Company Total | 4 |
| Gale | Cats Service | 2 |
| Gale | Cats Service | 6 |
| Gale | Cats Service | 1 |
|  | Cats Service Total | 9 |
| Gale | NY Company | 6 |
| Gale | NY Company | 8 |
|  | NY Company Total | 14 |
| Gale | XYZ Company | 1 |
|  | XYZ Company Total | 1 |
| John | NY Company | 3 |
| John | NY Company | 5 |
|  | NY Company Total | 8 |
| John | XYZ Company | 8 |
| John | XYZ Company | 5 |
|  | XYZ Company Total | 13 |
| Ken | ABC Company | 10 |
|  | ABC Company Total | 10 |
| Ken | NY Company | 2 |
| Ken | NY Company | 3 |
| Ken | NY Company | 5 |
|  | NY Company Total | 10 |
|  | Grand Total | 132 |

Any suggestions??

Comment: Why not just use SUMIFS: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Bob")`.

Comment: Why not [PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)?